# Time series standardization

Tags: time-series, stationarity, standardization, granger-causality

So, I'm studying and replicating the techniques applied in this [paper](http://journals.plos.org/plosone/article?id=10.1371/journal.pone.0161197).

The paper uses the Granger causality test to perform association analysis between bitcoin's price fluctuation and bitcoin forum's comments sentiment.

When studying the Granger causality test, I saw that the time series must be stationary. Otherwise the results might not be trustful. For that, the article says all data were transformed into z-scores for **standardization against the previous 10 days**. It also says:

> On a certain date $t$ ($t = 10$ in the paper), the z-score of a certain item $\mathbb{E}$, denoted by $Z_\mathbb{E}$, was defined as:
>   $Z_{\mathbb{E}_t} = (\mathbb{E} - \overline{x}(\mathbb{E})) \div \sigma(\mathbb{E})$, where $\overline{x}(\mathbb{E})$ and $\sigma(\mathbb{E})$ respectively represent the mean and standard deviation of each item for
>   every date.

From that statement I understood that one would calculate the mean and standard deviation of a 10 days period (say from day ""x"" to day ""x+9"", including both day ""x"" and ""x+9"") and then calculate the zscore for the day ""x+10"". Then, repeat this process for every date available.

So my quetions are:
Is this a correct interpretation? Is it a a common approach on transforming the time series into stationary? Is this approach anyway similar to first differentiation approach?